# Load macro with TWIG

Tags: php, twig

I installed TWIG in my project but I can't load my macro, I would like to create a file tests (For example testmacro.twig) who call my macro (For example test.twig), but I can not :(

test.twig

```
{% macro test (options) %}

    {% if options.titre is not empty %}
        coucou {{ options.titre }}
    {% endif %}     

{% endmacro }
```

testmacro.twig

```
{% import "/home/valentin/Bureau/htdocs/templates/test.twig" as test %}

{{ test.test ({ titre : 'aaaaaaah' }) }}
```

Error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Loader' with message 'Unable to find template "/home/valentin/Bureau/htdocs/templates/test.twig" (looked into: templates) in "testmacro.twig" at line 1.' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php:215 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php(139): Twig_Loader_Filesystem->findTemplate('/home/valentin/...') #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Twig/Environment.php(312): Twig_Loader_Filesystem->getCacheKey('/home/valentin/...') #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Twig/Environment.php(378): Twig_Environment->getTemplateClass('/home/valentin/...', NULL) #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Twig/Template.php(286): Twig_Environment->loadTemplate('/home/valentin/...', NULL) #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Twig/Environment.php(403) : eval()'d code(19): Twig_Template->loadTemplate('/home/valentin/...', 'testmacro.twig', 1) #5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Twig/Template.php(387): __TwigTemplate_e0a6b64206d91d57c5131f111d33ce0450565dc8429fccbaf4af635b1ac6ec27->doDisplay(Array, Array) #6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Twig/Template.php(355): Twig_T in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php on line 215
```

twig.php :

```
<?php
include_once('Twig/Autoloader.php');
Twig_Autoloader::register();

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates'); // Dossier contenant les templates
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
  'cache' => false
));
```

index.php

```
<?php
include('twig.php');
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('testmacro.twig');
echo $template->render(array());
```

?>

I don't understand .. :/

Can you help me please ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template paths are relative to the folder you've set as parameter in the `Twig_Loader_Filesystem`:

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates');
```

So in your case template paths start from the folder `templates`, this is also correct for `includes`, `macros`, `...` :

```
{% import 'test.twig' as test %}
```